# TypeError: Cannot find function hasNext in object (Folder with date ID)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, typeerror

I'm new to coding in javascript and google apps. I'm making a database that will automatically update new users into an aggregate sheet nightly.

My searchfolder() function won't execute because i keep getting the error "TypeError: Cannot find function hasNext in object Thu Jul 14 09:48:01 PDT 2016 INFO: Target. (line 24, file working daily)"

var files has .getfiles after DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId) so i haven't the slightest idea what the problem is

CODE:

```
var counter = 0;

function timeStamp(){
counter= (counter+1)
}

var files = "null"

function searchFolder() {
  var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
  // Log the name of every file in the folder.
 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in      
 folder
  while (files.hasNext()) { //loop log files in folder
  var file = files.next(); //log files in folder
  Logger.log(file.getName()); //logs name of file in folder
  var files = Logger.getLog();
  }
}

function autoUpdate(){ //updates monthly from newly imported daily
  if (counter == 1){ //counter is made to be 1 when day is uploaded to 
  monthly
  var ss =    
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc"); 
  //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as 
  active
  var range= ss.getRange("A1:A1"); 
  range.activate;  // activates range
  range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("1K7Rj4QK-  
  EVjf8lZ0BSew7iDeCtktqWjzgjoaVPe5jSc","sheet1!A1:G6")'); //Puts in 
  IMPORTRANGE into target as a STRING value (just words). Once it hits the 
  sheet, then SHEETS executes IMPORTRANGE not SCRIPTS. In Source sheet, 
  range is selected to import to target (ie A1:G6)
  counter=(counter-1)
  }
}

//searchFolder();
timeStamp();
autoUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared variable `files` two times. Also, pushing into log and then getting logs back is bad practice. Better use array instead. You got an error because variable `files` where you store file names is changed to log context after first loop, which means that there is no more function `hasNext` inside your `files` object (it is not of type `string`).

```
var counter = 0;

function timeStamp(){
counter= (counter+1)
}

var files = [];

function searchFolder() {
  var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
  // Log the name of every file in the folder.
 var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in folder
  while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getName());
}

function autoUpdate(){ //updates monthly from newly imported daily
  if (counter == 1){ //counter is made to be 1 when day is uploaded to monthly
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc"); 
  //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as 
  active
  var range= ss.getRange("A1:A1"); 
  range.activate;  // activates range
  range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("1K7Rj4QK-EVjf8lZ0BSew7iDeCtktqWjzgjoaVPe5jSc","sheet1!A1:G6")'); //Puts in IMPORTRANGE into target as a STRING value (just words). Once it hits the sheet, then SHEETS executes IMPORTRANGE not SCRIPTS. In Source sheet, range is selected to import to target (ie A1:G6)
  counter=(counter-1)
  }
}

searchFolder(); // After this function all file names are stored in variable `files`
timeStamp();
autoUpdate();
```

If you want to log all files in folder too, you can execute `Logger.log(files.join('\n'));`

Comment: This totally did the trick! thank you so much for educating me and fixing it, can't tell you how much of a lifesaver this is!